# ionic list fixed height accordion

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an an ionic list accordion that I would like to be of fixed height. meaning I do not want the whole accordion to scroll only inner list so that the headings of the accordion is visible at all times.

So it should work like the [jQuery](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) accordion

Here is a sample of my css:

```
.list .item.item-accordion {
  line-height: 38px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.09s all linear;
}
.list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide {
  line-height: 0px;
}
.list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide-add,
.list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide-remove {
  display: block !important;
}
```

I have made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Taylorsuk/pen/jPyjdm) for a demonstration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kinda works. It needs some tweaking, but hopefully will get you going in the right direction.

Edit your html to add a wrapper to the ng-repeat.

```
  <div class="ion-checkbox-viewport">
    <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="filter in group.filters | orderBy: 'name'" class="item-accordion" value="{{filter.name}}" ng-model="filter.checked" ng-change="ModifyFilter(filter)" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
        {{filter.name}}
    </ion-checkbox>
  </div>
```

Then add a css rule:

```
.ion-checkbox-viewport {
  max-height: 200px;
  width:100%;
  display:block !important;
  overflow:scroll !important;
}
```

All it does is wraps the ng-repeat in another parent element, then it sets a max height on that element and scrolling as needed.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVxwxP

Comment: How can I make it fill the viewport. The fixed height 200px is a little limiting given the devices I am going to be using it on. Many thanks Jim

Comment: My pleasure. I am heading out so I can't do a pen right now but your best bet is probably to use flexbox. You'd wrap the whole thing in a div that has height: 100%, then you'd use flexbox to make the currently expanded element have flex: 4 when everything else has a flex of 1. You might be able to do it using height: 100% without flexbox but it seems like the calculations would get tricky.

Comment: I tried the 100% idea and it didn't work for me unfortunately. I'm interested in the flexbox idea. Not used it before.

Comment: @Taylorsuk the more I think about it, for mobile compatibility you probably want something more like this: https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish   edit: don't link to comment

Comment: The main reason is because if you use some other kind of scrolling then it means that on small devices in landscape mode, you'd almost certainly have a scrolling target that is tiny or even invisible. Instead, if you go the route above then you'll be able to always fill the space but still accommodate  the extra content that comes in later when the accordion drops down.

Comment: On a phone I disable landscape so thats not a problem. I will have a play, thanks again.